# is there a way to append a variable to a class javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

i am currently trying to add my variable called "Exceldatasheetprice" (variable is a number) inside a class on a webpage

the class is called "currency-coins subContent"

i have tried this so far any help would be appriciated to add into my javascript

i want the variable appending just below the class

```
       $('.pagination.next').keyup(function(e){
            if (e.keycode == 39)
            e.preventDefault();
            var t = document.createElement("style");
            t.type = "text/css",
            t.innerText = "\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem {\n        height: 39px;\n    }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem .label {\n        font-size: 10px;\n  }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .auction {\n        margin-top: 0 !important;\n        font-size: 12px;\n        top: 4px;\n    }\n",
            document.head.appendChild(t)
            var elements = document.createElement('currency-coins subContent')
            elements.type = "text/css",
            elements.innerText = "\n   Exceldatasheetprice  {\n "
            setTimeout(function(){
                getPlayerDataFromSite();
            }, 500);
        });
    }
```

the part i added was

```
 var elements = document.createElement('currency-coins subContent')
            elements.type = "text/css",
            elements.innerText = "\n   Exceldatasheetprice  {\n
```

i dont think it was a very good attempt if anyone could help it would be great thank you

Comment: `document.createElement('currency-coins subContent')` <-- There is no such element and elements can't contain spaces in their names.

Answer (score 0):

document.createElement creates an html element of the type you pass in, so currency-coins subContent doesn't make sense here.  You probably want a div or something.  From there, you can use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add class(es) to it.

```
 var element = document.createElement('div');
 element.classList.add('currency-coins','subContent');
 element.innerText = "\n"+Exceldatasheetprice+"\n" ;
```

Comment: great , how do you position this on a part of a page ?